# Rotate or replace EMV keys?

Tags: key-management, key, emv, payment

I would like to better understand the mechanism of rotation of EMV keys used for payment cards.
Assuming that it intends to provide a rotation of the keys used for the production cards:

- just recycle the keys under Master Key and get a new cryptogram to use?
- generate new keys and replace the old ones?

In the event of a replacement, I think it makes sense to start using them only for the cards that will be produced at a later date without impacting the cards circulating. Obviously then the impacts on the actors who share that key (scheme?) should be evaluated;

- Is it possible to make coexist two sets of keys for different PAN ranges of the same BIN?

It would be interesting to get feedback from someone who handles these processes.